# Animating a child independent of parent

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

We are creating a system where elements in a display unit are defined through xml. This also means that the whole system is dynamic in nature. So there is no way of knowing whether an element will have a tween associated with it or not.

```
    <element id="name" type="txt" top="0" txt="Black look down" left="0" width="145" height="35"......>
    <transitions>
        <navIn>
        <tween type="default" orientation="horizontal" direction="1" time=".4" delay=".2" stagger="0" ease="Quint.easeOut" />
       </navIn>
       <navOut>
        <tween type="default" orientation="vertical" direction="1" time=".4" delay="0" stagger="0" ease="Quint.easeIn" />
        </navOut>
    </transitions>
</element>
```

Note that there are other elements around it and also that each element need not have a transition.

We can see that this element is a text element. Lets consider ( for the sake of simplicity ) that this text element is inside a box element. This box element can have other elements inside it like the text ( more than 1 ). The box will probably always have a transition associated with it. Now if this text element also has a transition it should work independently of the box transitions. Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see reasons (layering, visibility, mouseChildren, etc) you'd want to have a child belong to a parent but not receive it's geometric transformations.

It depends on the effect you're looking for exactly, but you can reverse the effects of the parent's affine transform (geometry - aka scale/rotate/translate) by applying the inverse of the parents' transform matrix, for example, to a container in between:

In this example I whipped up, the parent container (red dot) is being moved/rotated/scaled around while the child (blue dot) remains static because I've created a container in between 
that easily reverses the effects of the parent transforms using Matrix.invert (NOTE: calculations performed on every frame).  You could do it without a container, but then you'd need to take care how you Tweened the child.

You'll need to optimize it to your requirements, but I'm just showing that it is possible, if not easy.  =)

```
package
{
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.geom.Matrix;
  import flash.utils.setInterval;

  [SWF(width="800", height="600", frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]
  public class tst extends Sprite
  {

    public function tst():void
    {
      var prnt:Sprite = new Sprite();
      var cont:Sprite = new Sprite();
      var child:Sprite = new Sprite();

      prnt.addChild(cont);
      cont.addChild(child);

      prnt.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
      prnt.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);

      child.graphics.beginFill(0x0000ff);
      child.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);


      cont.addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, function(e:Event):void {
        var m:Matrix = prnt.transform.matrix.clone();
        m.invert();
        cont.transform.matrix = m;
      });

      var n:Number = 0;
      setInterval(function():void {
        prnt.x = 50+40*Math.cos(n);
        prnt.y = 50+40*Math.sin(n);
        prnt.scaleX = 3*Math.sin(n);
        prnt.rotation += 7*Math.cos(n);
        n += 0.1;
      }, 100);

      addChild(prnt);
    }
  }
}
```

See it [in action](http://www.onetacoshort.com/temp/independent_child.swf).

Comment: as explained above, this is not a good way to do it. Your solution is also a bid off (the child is not standing still, it's beeing moved a bit all the time)

Comment: Lol @ your downvote.  Again, sorry to show you up.  I didn't say it was a good idea, I said it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

When you adjust a setting on a parent, it will also be applied to the children. (moving, scaling, rotating)

So the transition of the box will always be applied all it's children. But surely they can have their own transitions. (Fx the box has a "move up" transition, and the text a "move left" transition, then the text will both move up and left.)

If you don't want the text position being affected by the box position, then don't add it as a child of the box.

Comment: Yeah . I get that. What I am looking for is an efficient solution in this scenario!

Comment: "If you don't want the text position being affected by the box position, then don't add it as a child of the box."  Sorry for the downvote, but in programming I rarely accept defeat so quickly.  =)

Comment: @JeffWard I have to disagree! I would say it's bad practice not following the most obvius and common rules (like children not being affected by parerent geometric transformation). If your idea doesn't fit into the system, the solution is not just to hack it until it works. Either adjust your idea to the system (usually will be the best thing, you will probably also find a better way to do it). If you can't follow the system, make your own!

Comment: I am "making my own" system.  If you want layering provided by the displaylist but not geometric transformations, I showed how to do it.  Think outside the box, friend.